# issue with getting video source from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video.js

I am trying to get sources of videos through javascript. The code below is working fine. However it only works for one video only, if I was to add the same code for multiple videos, none of the videos work. I am using `video.js` as the main player for videos.

html:

```
<source id="01" src="" type='video/mp4'/>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("01").src="link";
```

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique within a DOM.

Comment: @millhouse i have the id's as example like vd1, vd2 and so on

Comment: what kind of error occurs?

Comment: Can you post your multiple videos `html`?

Comment: the error i get is src not found when using video js but if i was to add just one line of code document.getElementById("vid1").src="link";
 it works fine. All videos are on different pages but i'm trying to use javascript to get the sources since the sources changes very often.

Comment: what exactly, do you mean when you say videos are in different pages

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing how your multiple videos are structured and how you're trying to access them with the same line of code.

Comment: @Samurai here is fiddle for some reason it doesn't work on fiddle but locally it does work http://jsfiddle.net/wp1Lpoaj/ for video only though

Comment: @mido22 okay lets say on page1 video is about cats and page 2 video is about dogs so from javascript on page1 it will get the source for cat video i made a fiddle but it doesn't work on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wp1Lpoaj/ but it does work if used locally.

Comment: @imdummynot you just need to load it then as already posted in the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/wp1Lpoaj/1/

Comment: @imdummynot show how these two pages interact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely need to reload the video after changing the Source. I give you an exemple with jQuery

```
var video = document.getElementById("01");
$(video).attr('src', "newlink.mp4");
video.load();
```

But you can achieve it without jquery

```
var video = document.getElementById("01");
video.src= "newlink.mp4";
video.load();
```

Comment: thanks for helping i'm trying to use custom flash player it's seems like it's the flash player issue i tried the locally on html page within html5 it works fine but when using it on external javascript it doesn't do anything thanks for helping again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the videojs API to change the source:

> videojs('YOUR_PLAYER_ID').src("/path/to/newlink.mp4")

This will work for flash and HTML5